# How to prove that cardinal numbers of sets and unions of them are equal

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A, B, C, D be sets.

If I know that $A\sim C$ and that $B\sim D$,

In addition I know that:

$C\cap D = \varnothing$ and also, $A\cap B = \varnothing$

Does it imply that $A\cup B\sim C\cup D$? How can this be proven?

Comment: This is trivial and in fact holds even if you drop the requirements that $A\cap B=\varnothing$ and $C\cap D=\varnothing$, which is less trivial, but still easy to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does, take one bijection $f:A\to B$ and another bijection $f:C\to D$.
Define $h:A\cup B \to C\cup D$ by $h(a)=f(a)$ if $a\in A$ and $h(b)=g(b)$ for $b\in B$.
Verify that $h$ is a bijection.

Note. The assumption that $A\cap B$ is only important when both $A$ and $B$ are finite (which happens exactly when both $C$ and $D$ are finite). If at least one of the sets is infinite then the result is valid, with a more complicated (but also more interesting) proof based on the [Schröder-Bernstein Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).